# How to center align this image with the text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center the rounded image with the text, however I can not succeed to it.

What should I change to my code to do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/zxwz5739/

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="team-1-member">
        <div class="round">
            <center>
                <img alt="Team Member" src="http://i.imgur.com/qIKR0Qt.gif">
            </center>
        </div>
            <h2>John Doe</h2>

    </div>
</div>

.team-1-member {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 48px;
}
.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.round img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.team-1 h2 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `<center>`. It's obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Comment: You are trying to center the image with respect to the text (and leave the text where it is), center only the image in the box, or center the image and the text in the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to .round add: display: inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

For .round, change your `margin-bottom: 10px;` to `margin: 0 auto 10px auto;`.

I'd also suggest getting rid of your `<center>` tags. They're technically not supposed to be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically remove your outer `div` and `center` and change the image itself to `display: inline-block`.

New HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="team-1-member">
        <img alt="Team Member" src="http://i.imgur.com/qIKR0Qt.gif" class="round" />
        <h2>John Doe</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

New CSS code:

```
.team-1-member {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 48px;
}

.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.team-1 h2 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Result as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4fat3m8/).